# Copy a column from result of query to a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (id,name,products) and a function with result(id,products)
how can i write a query that copy column "products" of result table to main table with id?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using specifically. SQL is a common language between multiple platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updating existing products:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyTable.Products = MyFunc.Products
FROM MyTable INNER JOIN MyFunction(params) as MyFunc on MyTable.ID = MyFunc.ID
```

For inserting new records:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(id, products)
SELECT id, products FROM MyFunction(params)
```

Assuming of course, that it's a table-valued function